# Receiving error "No state found with the key: preload" despite stating it in my index

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

```
 <script src = "phaser.js"></script>
 <script src = "Boot.js"></script>
 <script src = "preload.js"></script>
 <script src = "level1.js"></script>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            var Game = new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'');
            Game.state.add('Boot', game.Boot);
            Game.state.add('preload', game.preload);
            Game.state.add('level1', game.level1);
            Game.state.start('Boot');
     </script>
</body>
```

Preload is stated here, in the HTML Index, I then call for it in the boot JavaScript like this:

```
create:function(){
    this.state.start('preload')
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the scope is not used but the global Phaser variable: *Game*

**Boot.js**

```
var Boot = {
   create: function() {

      Game.state.start('preload');

   }
};
```

If you have more problems this is an excellent [tutorial](http://perplexingtech.weebly.com/game-dev-blog/using-states-in-phaserjs-javascript-game-developement)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to initialize the game object in this way at first:

```
var game = {};

game.Boot = {
    preload: function(){
    },
   create: function(){
    },
   update: function(){
    }
};
```

In your code I see that you call it like this:

```
Game.state.add('Boot', game.Boot);
```

not like this:

```
Game.state.add('Boot', Boot);
```

So, you should initialize the game object first.